# single check custom radio button in android

Tags: android, radio-button

this is code i want need only single radio button. i have create custom radio button and set id. i want need only single radio button checked at time .

```
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
    LinearLayout firstlin = new LinearLayout(this);
    rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
    rdbtn.setId(j);
    final RadioGroup rg =new RadioGroup(this);
        rg.addView(rdbtn);              
    rdbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
        responces=arr.get(rdbtn.getId());
        //rdbtn.setChecked(false); 
        }
    }); 
    firstlin.addView(rg);

                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull this code outside the loop, or else you are creating a new RadioGroup for each button:

```
final RadioGroup rg =new RadioGroup(this);
```

Also pull the LinearLayout outside the loop:

```
LinearLayout firstlin = new LinearLayout(this);
```

and

```
firstlin.addView(rg);
```

Comment: i have try this but not work .if you have any example for single check custom radio button then tell me. thanks